# Very, very large numbers in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, biginteger

How is it possible to deal with incredibly long (large) numbers in vb.net?

I am working on Problem 25 in Project Euler, and my program cannot handle these computations.

Is there a data type that can handle thousands of digits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

The point of the challenge is to make *you* write the code to handle big numbers.  Using a library definitely isn't the point.  You know how to solve it with a (large) piece of paper and a pencil, right?

Note how a large number you write on paper can also be a List(Of Digit).  All you gotta do is figure out how to add them.  And declare victory when the Count property turns into 1000.

Comment: Are the most significant digits of the answer 1070066266382...?

Comment: It's also for general use, how do I handle incredibly large numbers in my own programs unrelated to this?

Comment: You use Double or Decimal.  Double supports numbers with up to 308 digits, but can only compute the first 15 of them with accuracy.  Which is rarely a problem, the world around us isn't that big nor that accurate.  Accountants created their own world, served by Decimal.  Mathematicians created their own, nobody really cares about them.

Comment: What about for extreme precision?

Comment: Well, being able to accurately store the distance between the Sun and the Earth with a resolution of a micrometer has always been good enough for me.  Or the speed of a African laden swallow, making the observable difference of two of them arriving at the same destination well less than the wavelength of observable light.  Maybe you can come up with a less practical need for such precision?  But if you find one and have completed the challenge, you already know a solution.  Good thing. Obviously I'm having some fun at this at your expense.  I apologize, incurable flaw of an engineer's mind.

Comment: You used a Monty Python joke at my expense, it's completely okay.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the BigInteger function from the Microsoft Visual J# library(when your Framework version is < 4). Just add a reference to vjslib in your project.

Or [use String](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megamath/files/), but that could be slow.

Frome here: [Large Number Calculations](http://visualbasic.about.com/b/2007/12/15/large-number-calculations.htm)